# Creating Sencha Touch, Phone Gap project in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Having trouble creating a sencha project, with phone gap. My development machine is a Mac.

These are the steps I took.

- Downloaded phone gap from [link](http://phonegap.com/download-thankyou).
- created a project in xCode using `Cordova-based-application`
- Run the application in xCode.
- Got an error that the index.html file is missing so `R-click` on
  Project and added `www` folder. I unchecked `copy items to
  destination folder` and 'checked create folder references for any
  added folder'
- Once I added the `www` folder, I was unable to R-Click and add any
  files or create folders inside it. Here's the screen shot;

[image]

- Now, when I run the application, it says `Cordova is working`. I am unable to R-Click and add a file inside the `www` folder.

Why is this and how can I solve this ?

- I guess the next step i should take is to add the Sencha Touch 2 files in to this project. I am not sure about the steps i should get. So can someone kindly give me the steps or a good link (which gives step-by-step guidelines to make this work).

Am I correct up to now if I have missed any steps please correct me. I have been trying to make this work for more than 3 days now.

Note:

1. My ultimate goal is to run the application (Hello world code) in an
   iPhone and Android device. So Please help me.
2. I have gone through this [tutorial](http://www.sencha.com/learn/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap)

**UPDATE- AFTER ADDING SENCHATOUCH PROJECT TO MY APPLICATION**

[image]

When I expand the SenchaTouch Project

[image]

Comment: Please top putting "Beginner" on all of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Finder to manage the files. Two finger click on the root project and select "Show in Finder". Once you have that directory open, copy your Sencha Touch project to the directory using Finder. You can edit those files in XCode but you cannot do most of the normal file functions in XCode because the WWW directory is referenced directory.

Comment: After opening the project in finder do i have to Drag-and-Drop the SenchaTouch directory to the `WWW` folder or outside the `WWW` folder (with my project it self) ?

Comment: I have updated my Question, after adding the SenchaTouch Project. Could you kindly have a look and tell me if what i have done is correct ?

Comment: Can anyone tell me what i should do to get the correct folder structure of the project, I have included scren-shots of my project structure above.

Comment: You are close...the touch project should be under the WWW directory and your initial index.html should be in the WWW directory. You have your touch project in a directory that would not be accessed by PhoneGap(Cordova) initially.